# Populate child table with primary key from parent table

Tags: java, mysql

I have a `customer` table and an `address` table.  I'm trying to automatically insert the primary key value into the `address` table.  Initially, I had it the other way around and it worked, however, the relationship was wrong since I wasn't able to delete cascade when a customer was deleted.  Information inserts into the `customer` table but not the `address table`.  This is what I have.  Any insight would be appreciated.

```
 /**
 * Add a new customer.
 * @param customer The customer to be added.
 * @return customerId.
 * @throws SQLException If an error happens.
 */
public int addCustomer(Customer customer) throws SQLException {
    // first insert the address of the customer
    //int addressId = addAddress(customer.getAddress());

    // next insert the customer
    var sql = "INSERT INTO customer (customerId, customerName, active, createdBy)" +
            " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

    var statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
    statement.setInt(1, 0);
    statement.setString(2, customer.getName());
    //statement.setInt(3, addressId);
    statement.setBoolean(3, customer.isActive());
    statement.setString(4, customer.getCreatedBy());

    statement.execute();
    var generatedKeys = statement.getGeneratedKeys();
    generatedKeys.next();
    return (int) generatedKeys.getLong(1);
}
/**
 * Add a new address to the database.
 * @param address The address to be added.
 * @throws SQLException if an error happens.
 */
public void addAddress(Address address) throws SQLException {
    
    int customerId = addCustomer(address.getCustomer());
    
    var sql = "INSERT INTO address (addressId, customerId, address, address2, cityId, countryId, postalCode, phone, createdBy) " +
            "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    var statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    statement.setInt(1, 0);
    statement.setInt(2, customerId);
    statement.setString(3, address.getAddress());
    statement.setString(4, address.getAddress2());
    statement.setInt(5, address.getCity().getId());
    statement.setInt(6, address.getCountry().getId());
    statement.setString(7, address.getPostalCode());
    statement.setString(8, address.getPhone());
    statement.setString(9, address.getCreatedBy());

    statement.execute();
```

}

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Got some help with just updating the delete customer method so it deletes the associated address along with the customer.

```
enter code here
    public void deleteCustomer(Customer customer) throws Exception {
    var appointments =
            appointmentRepository.findCustomerAppointments(customer.getId());

    if(!appointments.isEmpty()){
        throw new RuntimeException("Constraint Violation");
    }
    var deleteAddress = "DELETE FROM address WHERE addressId = ?";
    var statementDeleteAddress = connection.prepareStatement(deleteAddress);
    statementDeleteAddress.setInt(1, customer.getAddress().getId());
    statementDeleteAddress.execute();
    var sql = "DELETE FROM customer WHERE customerId = ?";
    var statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    statement.setInt(1, customer.getId());
    statement.execute();
```